# Expressão regular para 2 casos específicos

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

Eu queria duas regexp para padronizar um campo.
Segue os dois valores que preciso uma expressão regular.

1. `1-167106651950`

   Um número de 0 a 9, um traço obrigatório e mais 12 números de 0 a 9.
2. `SP4:01:342310`

   Duas letras maiúsculas podendo ser SP ou RJ, um número de 1 a 9, dois pontos obrigatório, dois dígitos de 0 a 9,  dois pontos obrigatório e mais seis dígitos de 0 a 9.

Eu criei a seguinte regexp para o primeiro caso, mas ele não limita o número de dígitos que eu digito.

```
([0-9\-]+)\-[0-9]+
```

Para a segunda eu não conseguir fazer nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos ver porque sua regex não funciona.

Os colchetes (`[]`) correspondem a uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): eles servem para indicar que você quer qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles.

Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b` **ou** a letra `c`" (**apenas uma delas**, qualquer uma serve). É uma expressão que corresponde a apenas **um** caractere.

No caso, está sendo usado `0-9`, que significa "os dígitos de 0 a 9". Portanto, `[0-9]` aceita qualquer dígito de 0 a 9. Repare que o hífen (`-`) tem um significado especial, pois ele serve para definir um intervalo entre dois caracteres. Como você também colocou outro hífen, porém com barra invertida antes (`\-`), este passa a ser interpretado como o próprio caractere hífen.

Portanto, `[0-9\-]` significa "um dígito de 0 a 9 **ou** um hífen". Qualquer um desses caracteres serve, como podemos ver no exemplo abaixo:

```js
console.log(/[0-9\-]/.test('1')); // true
console.log(/[0-9\-]/.test('-')); // true
```

Já o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" do que está imediatamente antes dele. Então `[0-9\-]+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de dígito ou hífen". Ou seja, se tiver vários dígitos, serve, e se tiver vários hífens também serve (e qualquer combinação destes caracteres também serve).

```js
console.log(/[0-9\-]+/.test('123112')); // true
console.log(/[0-9\-]+/.test('-----')); // true
console.log(/[0-9\-]+/.test('-1-3-432---111-')); // true
```

Para obter apenas um número de 0 a 9, basta usar `[0-9]` ou `\d` (no final da resposta coloquei uma observação sobre `[0-9]` versus `\d`, já que nem sempre eles são a mesma coisa).
Para o hífen, não precisa colocar a barra invertida se ele estiver fora dos colchetes, basta colocar `-` e pronto.

E para determinar uma quantidade específica, coloque este valor entre chaves. No caso, você quer 12 dígitos, então basta fazer `[0-9]{12}` (exatamente 12 ocorrências de qualquer dígito de 0 a 9).

Também recomendo usar os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que a string só tem o que está determinado dentro da regex. Então a regex para o caso 1 fica assim:

```js
console.log(/^[0-9]-[0-9]{12}$/.test('1-167106651950')); // true
console.log(/^[0-9]-[0-9]{12}$/.test('123-167106651950')); // false
console.log(/^[0-9]-[0-9]{12}$/.test('1-A67106651950')); // false
```

Se você não usar os marcadores `^` e `$`, pode acabar com falsos positivos:

```js
console.log(/[0-9]-[0-9]{12}/.test('abc1-167106651950def')); // true
```

Repare que a string começa com `abc` e termina com `def`. Mesmo assim a regex retorna `true`, porque ela contém um trecho que corresponde à expressão. Usando `^` e `$` você garante que ela só vai ter o que você especificou.

---

Para o caso 2, podemos usar [o operador de alternância `|`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) para as opções "SP" ou "RJ": `(SP|RJ)`.

Para o número de 1 a 9, usamos os colchetes: `[1-9]`. Os dois pontos são colocados diretamente como `:`, e para os demais dígitos usamos a quantidade entre chaves, da mesma forma que foi feito no caso 1. Não esqueça também de usar os marcadores `^` e `$`:

```js
console.log(/^(SP|RJ)[1-9]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{6}$/.test('SP4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(/^(SP|RJ)[1-9]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{6}$/.test('RJ4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(/^(SP|RJ)[1-9]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{6}$/.test('AB4:01:342310')); // false
```

---

Se você quer uma única regex que valida os dois casos, basta juntar as expressões anteriores com `|`.
No exemplo abaixo eu também uso a classe `RegExp` do JavaScript, para evitar repetição de código:

```js
let re = RegExp(/^([0-9]-[0-9]{12})|((SP|RJ)[1-9]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{6})$/);
console.log(re.test('SP4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(re.test('RJ4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(re.test('1-167106651950')); // true

console.log(re.test('123-167106651950')); // false
console.log(re.test('AB4:01:342310')); // false
```

---

### `[0-9]` versus `\d`

Geralmente ambos são equivalentes. O único detalhe é que dependendo da linguagem/engine/configuração, o `\d` também pode corresponder a [outros caracteres que representam dígitos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), como por exemplo os caracteres `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes).

No caso do JavaScript, esta opção está desabilitada por padrão, então tanto faz usar um ou outro:

```js
let re = RegExp(/^(\d-\d{12})|((SP|RJ)[1-9]:\d{2}:\d{6})$/);
console.log(re.test('SP4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(re.test('RJ4:01:342310')); // true
console.log(re.test('1-167106651950')); // true

console.log(re.test('123-167106651950')); // false
console.log(re.test('AB4:01:342310')); // false
```

Repare que eu não troquei o `[1-9]` por `\d`, já que `\d` pega todos os dígitos de 0 a 9, enquanto `[1-9]` não inclui o zero.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante no meu entendimento.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d-\d{12}$/
```

e

```
/^[A-Z]{2}[1-9]:\d{2}:\d{6}$/
```

Se apenas SP e RJ forem validos, utilize

```
/^(SP|RJ)[1-9]:\d{2}:\d{6}$/
```

Pois `[SP|RJ]{2}` aceitará SP, RJ, PS e JR.

Comment: Olá. Poderia detalhar mais a sua resposta?

Comment: Valeu. Não sabia que havia diferencia entre (SP|RJ) e [SP|RJ]. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Apenas melhorando a resposta anterior, na segunda expressão você disse que as letras serão `SP` ou `RJ`, porem com a regex `/^[A-Z]{2}[1-9]:\d{2}:\d{6}$/` ele aceitaria qualquer conjunto de duas letras, para limitar para `SP` ou `RJ` utilize:

```
/^[SPRJ]{2}[1-9]:\d{2}:\d{6}$/
```

Comment: Essa solução atende melhor ao que estava pedindo. Obrigado

Comment: @LeonardoVinicius O problema é que `[SP|RJ]{2}` aceita outras strings, como `PR`, `J|` e até mesmo `||`, veja aqui: https://regex101.com/r/9I9Md6/1

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora ele não pega mais `||` ou `J|` por exemplo, apenas a junção das 4 letras `SPRJ`

Comment: Gabriel, `[SPRJ]{2}` ainda aceita strings como `SS`, `PP` ou `JP`. Os colchetes indicam que qualquer caractere dentro deles serve: `[SPRJ]` significa *"a letra `S` **ou** a letra `P`, **ou** a letra `R`, **ou** a letra `J`"*. E o `{2}` indica que vc quer 2 ocorrências destas letras - **qualquer** combinação delas, [**veja aqui**](https://regex101.com/r/ZSiYVN/1). O problema são os colchetes, vc deve retirá-los e usar `(SP|RJ)` - veja as 2 respostas acima que explicam isso. Dentro dos colchetes, tanto faz a ordem, `[SPRJ]` é o mesmo que `[SRJP]`, pois ambos aceitam os mesmos caracteres.

Comment: Entendi, não lembrava dessa diferenciação entre `[]` e `()`, obrigado pela resposta.